# Is it possible to deeplink from a facebook post to an app and does it need to be approved by facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, deep-linking

I would like to have my app post to facebook and then when "friends" see the link, they can click on it and since it is a deeplink, clicking on it would take the user to the app store if the app isnt downloaded otherwise it would take them to the correct page of the app. Would this need approval from Facebook?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks, http://applinks.org/

Comment: yes, I saw this. Doesn't seem like you need approval given it's all open source.

Comment: If you already saw that, then why are you still asking whether it was possible?

Answer (score 1):

No approval needed, but in most cases this is currently not possible — Facebook has decided to block the functionality. The best option is to post a link pointing to a page on your website, and then open your app from there.

In other words, you can't open a link from the news feed and have it launch the app. However you *can* open a link to your website, and once the website is open you can launch your app successfully from there. This is the approach we currently use at [Branch.io](https://branch.io)

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks/android ? This mentions you can - unless it hasn't been updated?

Comment: The App Links standard was an amazing idea that Facebook has pretty much let die. I believe it is still supported in the main Facebook app on Android, but I haven't actually tested comprehensively in the last few weeks. Totally broken on iOS however :(